# LinkedIn Oauth - Revoke access from C#

Tags: c#, linkedin-api, http-delete

I have my users already authenticated to my LinkedIn app but I also want to give them the possibility to de-authenticate from my app any given time.

I think I'm just missing the http delete url to do it but i'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the OAuth specification allows a Client to deauthorise itself.  This is left up the the user going to the OAuth provider and doing it themselfs.

Comment: Yeah. I think so too. Same goes for twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OAuth protocol is specifically designed to not allow what you are attempting to accomplish. The OAuth security model introduces a third concept to the traditional client-server authentication model, and this is called the resource owner.  The resource owner (your end-users) is the only party that can grant and revoke access.  Perhaps you could provide a message to your users that they should visit LinkedIn to revoke access to assist them with that process (I suppose you could also redirect them to LinkedIn's website).  Ultimately though, if I were the end-user, I'd want to visit LinkedIn myself to revoke access.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-do-end-users-revoke-oauth-tokens) entry on the developer forum.

Comment: I was thinking on doing it from my app, but I think this is not possible since LinkedIn doesn't allow third-party applications to revoke access to apps even if it is your own app. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C# programmer, but what I suggest you do is give them a revoke access button. When that button is clicked, your software would delete the access key which was stored there. If the access token is no longer stored anywhere, they will be unable to access your application, which would mean the same as deauthentication.

I hope this helps.